ffmpeg.wasm does not support nodejs
I use ffmpeg in the next js version and an error occurs
Error: ffmpeg.wasm does not support nodejs
"next": "14.1.4",
"@ffmpeg/ffmpeg":"^0.12.10",
"@ffmpeg/util": "^0.12.1",
In another application this code works the only difference is the architecture in this code I am using FSD.
'use client'
 import { FFmpeg } from '@ffmpeg/ffmpeg';
 import { fetchFile, toBlobURL } from '@ffmpeg/util';
 import { useRef, useState } from 'react';

 type useTranscodeProps = {
   file: any,
  }

export const useTranscode = ({ file }: useTranscodeProps) => {
 const [blobVideo, setBlobVideo] = useState(null)
 const ffmpegRef = useRef(new FFmpeg());
 const [resize, setResize] = useState<string>('scale=400:720')
 const [resizing, setResizing] = useState(false)
 const [resized, setResized] = useState(false)

 const load = async () => {
     const baseURL = 'https://unpkg.com/@ffmpeg/core@0.12.6/dist/umd'
     const ffmpeg = ffmpegRef.current;

 await ffmpeg.load({
     coreURL: await toBlobURL(`${baseURL}/ffmpeg-core.js`, 'text/javascript'),
     wasmURL: await toBlobURL(`${baseURL}/ffmpeg-core.wasm`, 'application/wasm'),
     });
 }

 const transcode = async () => {
 const ffmpeg = ffmpegRef.current;
 setResizing(true);

 await ffmpeg.writeFile(file.name, await fetchFile(file));


 ffmpeg.on('progress', (e) => {
     console.log(Math.round(e.progress * 100));

    })
 await ffmpeg.exec([
     '-i', file.name,
         '-vf', resize,
         '-r', '30',
         'output.webm'
     ]);
     const data = await ffmpeg.readFile('output.webm');
     console.log(data)

    if (data) {
         setResizing(false);
     }
     return new Blob([data.buffer], {
         type: 'video/webm'
     });
 };

 return { load, transcode, setResize, setResized, blobVideo, resizing, resize, resized }
 }

Changing the version didn't help

Deployed on local host
